# Firebase crashes with "unrecognized selector" at FIRApp.configure() with swift3

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, google-analytics

I wanted to use Firebase library (google analytics) to track my app users...

I implemented Firebase with Carthage (swift 3).
but there was an error on Firebase.h on this line:

```
 #import <FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h>
```

I fixed the error with manually adding a firebase example project classes to my app.

Here is the screen shot of what I imported to my project
[image]

Now there is no error anywhere but when I run the app, I face with a crash at this function in appdelegate:

```
   override init() {
    FIRApp.configure() // <--- here
}
```

And here is the reason:

> reason: '+[NSData gtm_dataByGzippingData:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x105ff5338'

Any idea whats happening?

Comment: Can you check if you added **every** framework inside the folder you downloaded? The folder also has a list which tells you which frameworks to include. Also include the ones which sound like they are not important. (I fixed this in my app by adding "GoogleToolboxForMac" which I thought to be only for Mac OS apps)

Comment: Thanks man, "GoogleToolboxForMac"  was not there, how do I get this file?

Comment: This [direct link](https://firebase.google.com/download/ios) to the firebase download page gives you all possible firebase frameworks. GoogleToolboxForMac should be in there somewhere